# Major translation theories

Tags: translation

I need some help from a person who have a degree from Translations. I am looking for a brief informations about a major translation theories in English version but everytime I find something really useful, it turns out to be very comprehensive and I need just strict, clear definitions. Would be very glad for any kind of your help!

Comment: You're not gonna get what you're looking for. Languages are sprawling, complex, and unavoidably messy. Translation theories will be doubly so, to account for, at a minimum, two languages.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics SE :)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Wikipedia entry on translation? Often Wikipedia can be a good starting point if you want to gather some information on a subject. Just don't cite it in your course work (instead track down the actual sources). If Wikipedia is till too comprehensive for you then you might be looking for a level simplicity in your explanations that will be hard to find in the scholarly literature.